# NSString into NSData

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsdata

I wanna have a `NSString` object as `NSData`. Later this NSData-Object should return his stringValue with:

```
NSData *data;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`string` shouldn't be nil... =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataUsingEncoding:`